# Who was arrested at El Cojo with Eliot de Castro?

Tags: russia, colonial-america, spanish-empire, california

According to Bancroft's "History of California" II:274, Spanish authorities acting on Governor Sola's orders detained Eliot de Castro, working for the Russian-American Company, along with "an American and four Russians". Who were the others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the 1815 diary of Antipatr Baranov, as translated by Irina V. Wender and appearing in "So Far From Home", edited by Glenn J. Farris (Heyday, 2012):

> Along with Mr. Elliot were captured the following people: Fedor Sokolov, Dmitrii Shushkov, Petr Drushinin, American from Boston Liza [ed: Elijah?] Coal, Osip Volkov and Afansii Klimovskij. All were taken to the port of Santa Barbara.

Comment: Not bad, that only took two weeks to answer!